# Screen not refreshing when user logs in with Firebase Authentication

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication

I have a Flutter app in which I am using [firebase_auth](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_auth/) `^0.18.1+2` to log the user in with an email/password. There are two screens:

- Home screen: where the user is presented the option to log in
- Dashboard screen: the first screen to be shown when logged in

After the user logs in, however, the app does not refresh to show the Dashboard; the Home screen continues to appear. Can anyone advise?

After logging in, only when I perform a Hot Restart does the Dashboard appear.

`main.dart`:

```
MultiProvider(
    providers: [
      // Provider 1
      // ...
      // Provider 2
      // ...
      Provider<AuthService>(
        create: (_) => AuthService(),
      ),
      // Provider 4
      // ...
      // Provider 5
      // ...
    ],
    child: App(),
),
```

`auth_service.dart`:

```
Stream<User> get authStateChanges => FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges();
```

`app.dart`:

```
final AuthService authService =
    Provider.of<AuthService>(context, listen: false);

return MaterialApp(
  debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
  home: StreamBuilder<User>(
    stream: authService.authStateChanges,
    builder: (context, snapshot) {
      if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.active) {

        if (snapshot.hasData) {
        authService.firebaseUser = snapshot.data;

          return Scaffold(
            body: FutureBuilder<DocumentSnapshot>(
              future: authService.fetchExtraUserData(),
              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                  if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.active) {
                      authService.user = snapshot.data;

                      // Dashboard does not appear, however Flutter logging shows that Dashboard
                      // initState() is being called in the background.

                      if (snapshot.hasData) {
                         return Dashboard();
                      } else {
                         return Scaffold(
                            backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                            body: Center(
                               child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                             ),
                          );
                      }
                  } else {
                      return Scaffold(
                      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                      body: Center(
                         child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                        ),
                    );
                  }
              },
            ),
          );
        } else {
          return Home();
        }
      } else {
        return Scaffold(
          backgroundColor: Colors.white,
          body: Center(
            child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
          ),
        );
      }
    },
  ),
);
```

I have also tried the following with no luck:

- Removing the `FutureBuilder` which calls `authService.fetchExtraUserData()`
- Moving `StreamBuilder` above `MaterialApp`

  ```
  return StreamBuilder<User>(
      stream: authService.authStateChanges,
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        return MaterialApp(
          debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
          home: snapshot.hasData ? Dashboard() : Home(),
        );
      },
    );
  ```

It is also interesting to see that logging out works correctly - the user is returned to the Home screen. This shows that `authStateChanges` is working correctly in this case.

```
logout(BuildContext context) async => await authService.signOut();
```

`flutter doctor` output:

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel beta, 1.23.0-18.1.pre, on Mac OS X 10.15.7 19H2 x86_64)

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.1)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 12.3)
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Android Studio (version 4.1)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.52.0)
[✓] Connected device (3 available)
```

Comment: which screen is appearing?

Comment: @PeterHaddad The Home screen. The Dashboard screen should appear instead when logged in. I have updated the question to clarify this

Comment: Why are you using a FutureBuilder when displaying the Dashboard if you are displaying the Dashboard without considering whether the future (in this case  authService.fetchExtraUserData() ) is complete? It seems unnecessary, unless I'm missing something here.

Comment: Maybe the `authService.user = snapshot.data;` assignment is causing the StreamBuilder to rebuild. That would mean there is a cycle. Better avoid side-effects in build methods (`authService.firebaseUser = snapshot.data;`, `authService.fetchExtraUserData()`, `authService.user = snapshot.data;`)

Comment: @TanayNeotia My mistake, `snapshot.hasData` was omitted from the sample code (which I have updated now). The issue still persists however.

Comment: Just to make sure, can you try renaming the second `snapshot` (in the `FutureBuilder` for `authService.fetchExtraUserData()` to something like `snapshot1` instead? I want to eliminate the possibility of the `snapshot` within that `FutureBuilder` referencing the `snapshot` inside the original `FutureBuilder` just in case that is happening.

Comment: @TanayNeotia Thanks for the help - I actually tried that already, but still no luck!

Comment: You wrap `StreamBuilder` and `FutureBuilder ` make the structure looks complicated. Have you tried to print out all **snapshot** inside both builder to see what happen then? One thing I see is that the `FutureBuilder` only have waiting/done state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I have a demo which does work perfectly fine, let me post the relevant parts:

**main.dart** I used `ChangeNotifierProvider.value()`

```
...
return MultiProvider(
        providers: [
          ChangeNotifierProvider.value(
            value: AuthenticationService.instance(),
          ),
        ],
        child: MaterialApp(
          theme: ThemeData(
            primarySwatch: Colors.red,
          ),
          home: _screenMaker(context),
        ));
...
```

This is my _screenMaker Widget in the `main.dart` which is receiving the realtime state since im working with `Consumers` from the provider Package

```
Widget _screenMaker(BuildContext context) {
  return Consumer<AuthenticationService>(
    builder: (ctx, AuthenticationService auth, _) {
      switch (auth.status) {
        case Status.Uninitialized:
          return Splash();
        case Status.Unauthenticated:
        case Status.Authenticating:
          return LoginPage();
        case Status.NoVerification:
          return Verification();
        case Status.Authenticated:
          return UserInfoPage(
            user: auth.user,
          );
      }
    },
  );
}
```

Lets look at my `AuthentificationService` class, Im going to post the complete content but the magic for the state management is happening at the beginning after my getters:

```
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';

enum Status { Uninitialized, Authenticated, Authenticating, Unauthenticated , NoVerification}

class AuthenticationService with ChangeNotifier {
  FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  User _user;
  Status _status = Status.Uninitialized;

  Status get status => _status;
  User get user => _user;


  // Magic happens here
  AuthenticationService.instance() : _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance {
    _auth.authStateChanges().listen((firebaseUser) {
      print('--- authstate listening');
      if (firebaseUser == null) {
        _status = Status.Unauthenticated;
      } else if(firebaseUser != null && firebaseUser.emailVerified == false) {
        _status = Status.NoVerification;
      } else {
        _user = firebaseUser;
        _status = Status.Authenticated;
      }
      notifyListeners();
    });
  }


  Future<bool> signIn(String email, String password) async {
    try {
      _status = Status.Authenticating;
      notifyListeners();
      await _auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email: 'admin@admin.de', password: 'admin123');

      if(_auth.currentUser.emailVerified == null){
        _status = Status.Unauthenticated;
        print('--- user email verified is null');
        notifyListeners();
      }
   
      if(_auth.currentUser.emailVerified != true) {
        _status = Status.Authenticated;
        return true;
      } else {
        print('--- user needs confirmation');
        try {
        _status = Status.NoVerification;
        await user.sendEmailVerification();
        signOut();
        return true;
     } catch (e) {
        print('--- An error occured while trying to send email verification');
        print(e.message);
     }
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print('--- $e');
      signOut();
      notifyListeners();
      return false;
    }
  }



  // Signout function
  Future signOut() async {
    _auth.signOut();
    _status = Status.Unauthenticated;
    notifyListeners();
    return Future.delayed(Duration.zero);
  }

}
```

Thats everything you need. Read more about Consumers, this is a really powerful article for understanding it:
https://medium.com/flutter-community/managing-flutter-state-using-provider-e26c78060c26

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is because of the `false` parameters passed into the `provider.of<T>()` call.

Try `final AuthService authService = Provider.of<AuthService>(context);`

which tried to listen to a value exposed with the provider, from outside of the widget tree.

Comment: Thank you, but still no luck unfortunately. The screen still does not refresh to show the Dashboard.

Answer (score 0):

```
final AuthService authService =
Provider.of<AuthService>(context, listen: false);
```

In this line argument `listen: false` tells the widget to not rebuild when the state changes(user logs in).

Try removing `listen: false` from the provider.

Also
instead of creating provider as

```
Provider<AuthService>(
    create: (_) => AuthService(),
  )
```

which only exposes Auth Service values to widget tree and does not rebuild widget tree when state changes.

Use `ChangeNotifierProvider` to listen to changes and rebuild your widget tree like this

```
ChangeNotifierProvider(
    create: (context) => AuthService(),
)
```

Comment: Removing `listen: false` did not work unfortunately. I have updated the question to show how `AuthService` is created.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but still no luck after using `ChangeNotifierProvider`.

Answer (score 0):

Ok Try this,

First modify your firebase api class like this

```
 Stream<User> get user {
    return auth.onAuthStateChanged
        .map((FirebaseUser user) => _userFromFirebase(user));
  }


  User _userFromFirebase(FirebaseUser user) {
    return user != null ? User(id: user.uid) : null;
  }
```

after in your main.dart file modify like this

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamProvider<User>.value(
      value: AuthService().user,
      child: MaterialApp(
        theme: ThemeData(scaffoldBackgroundColor: Colors.blueAccent),
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        home: LoginWrapper(),
        //home: McqLoader(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

make Login wrapper class like this

```
class LoginWrapper extends StatelessWidget {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    
    final user = Provider.of<User>(context);
    if (user == null) {
      return Login();
    } else {
      return DashboardPage(id: user.id,);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class LandingPage extends StatelessWidget {
   @override
   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   final auth = Provider.of<AuthBase>(context);
   return StreamBuilder<Object>(
     stream: auth.onAuthChange,
     builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.active) {
            User user = snapshot.data;
            if (user == null) {
               return SignIn();
            }else {
               return HomePage();
            }
         }
            return CupertinoActivityIndicator();
      },
    );
  }
}
```